# PyCharm: unable to view subclass of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

### Situation

PyCharm has a neat built-in [viewer for pandas dataframes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-as-array.html). However this viewer doesn't seem to be available for dataframe subclasses.

The PyCharm 2018.2.4 screenshot below shows a simple example. As you can see the option `View as DataFrame` is available for the standard dataframe, but not for the dataframe subclass.

[image: pycharm 2018.2.4 screenshot]

Below is the example code again, but in text format:

```
import pandas as pd

class SubDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    pass

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=['a','b','c'])
sdf = SubDataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=['a','b','c'])
```

### Question

Is there any way to enable the PyCharm dataframe viewer for dataframe subclasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution doesn't require creating a temporary variable during debugging, and it also allows you to see the original DataFrame without being transposed or missing headers.

In your subclass, add this:

```py
@property
def base_class_view(self):
    # use this to view the base class, needed for debugging in some IDEs.
    return pd.DataFrame(self)
```

Now when debugging with PyCharm, you can click the down arrow next to your DataFrame in the `Variables` viewer. You should see the `base_class_view` property, then click `View as DataFrame` to the right of that.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any option you can enable but you can to expand the variable `sdf` by clicking the small arrow to the left of the variable name.

There, you have several options:

- View `T` of `T` (i.e., the transpose of the transpose) as a DataFrame (you should see clickable links)
- View `_get_values` or `_values` or `values` as an array in the viewer (same, there should be a clickable link)

It's the only way that I currently see within PyCharm to do what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've settled on another work-around. I copy the data contents of my subclass-dataframe to a standard dataframe like so:

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(sdf)
```

which I then open in the PyCharm dataframe viewer.